# Падает сайт при включении прослушки xdebug в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Сайт работает на Apache 2.2.22
PHP 5.3.13
xdebug 2.2.0

Конфиги php.ini

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]

xdebug.remote_enable = On

xdebug.profiler_enable = off

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off

xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p

xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"

xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"

xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"

xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"

xdebug.remote_autostart=on

xdebug.remote_connect_back=on

xdebug.remote_port=9001

xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

Всё прекрасно работало, пока не стал работать с файликом 4498 строк. Когда доходит до этого файла, сайт отваливается белым экраном.

Подскажите как это можно устранить.

Answer (score 1):

Включайте лог и смотрите, что происходит:

```
xdebug.remote_log="/path/to/file"
```

Скорее всего xdebug падает в segfault.
Попробуйте автостарт отключить, пусть срабатывает только если есть шары в файле.

Comment: В segfault xdebug не падает. Проблемы возникают во время дебага на Drupal. Особых закономерностей падения не наблюдается.

Answer (score 0):

Увеличил объем памяти вопреки предупреждениям - заработало как часики

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 300M
```